# RegEx not working in directive - Angular 4

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I created a directive that validates what the user enters in text field. User can enter numbers, dots and commas but not anything else.

The validator works when entering numbers, but I cannot enter commas and dots.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInputValidator]'
})
export class InputValidatorDirective {

private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^[0-9]{1,2}([,.][0-9]{1,2})?$/);

// Allow key codes for special events
// Backspace, tab, end, home
private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home'];

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
}

@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    debugger
    // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
        return;
    }

    let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    let next: string = current.concat(event.key);
    if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

}

I've tested the regex online and it works for numbers, dots and commas but inside the app I can't enter dots or commas. What is wrong?

Comment: Because when you enter `12.`, it doesn't match the regex

Comment: Am I using wrong function (match) ? Is it possible restrict input so that comma and dot cannot be first characters?

Comment: No. Since you are checking every time user press a key, when user wants to enter '12.3', on the 3rd key stroke, the string would become `12.`, which fails the regex check. Solution is either allow user to enter anything, and validate once focus leaves the input, or depending on the input, you might be able to craft a regex that allows the intermediate states

Comment: Can the regex be modified so that commas and dots cannot be first characters in the string?

Comment: Thank you, this gave me an idea on how to modify my regex.

Comment: Try `private regex: RegExp = /^[0-9]{1,2}([,.][0-9]{0,2})?$/;`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works perfectly and exactly what I need, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
private regex: RegExp = /^[0-9]{1,2}([,.][0-9]{0,2})?$/;
                                               ^
```

Note that `{0,2}` quantifier makes `[0-9]` match *zero*, one or two digits, and thus the `2.` like values will no longer stop user from typing a number with a fractional part.